# wxWebView compile issue on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ubuntu-18.04

I have been unable to compile wxWebView in my C++ code.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/wxhtml.h>
#include <wx/webview.h>

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();

    wxPanel    *panel;
    wxBoxSizer *topsizer;
    wxMenuBar  *menubar;
    wxMenu     *file;
    wxWebView  *webView;    // <---- HERE
    wxString    editorURL;
};
```

I get the following compiler errors (snippet):

```
g++ -c `wx-config --cxxflags` -o helloworld.o helloworld.cpp
helloworld.cpp:20:5: error: ‘wxWebView’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘wxWeakRef’?
 wxWebView  *webView;
 ^~~~~~~~~
 wxWeakRef
```

Some more information on system configuration:

- wxWidgets 3.0
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Included web view file: wx/webview.h

The only thing I can think of is I am missing a package in apt-get or I have conflicting packaging.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep webview
ii  libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5:amd64         3.0.4+dfsg-3                        amd64        wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ 3 webview library runtime)
ii  libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev               3.0.4+dfsg-3                        amd64        wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK+ 3 webview library development)

$ dpkg -l | grep webkit
ii  gir1.2-webkit-3.0:amd64                    2.4.11-3ubuntu3                     amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+ - GObject introspection data
ii  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64                   2.20.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1             amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+ - GObject introspection data
ii  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64                 2.20.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1             amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+
ii  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64                   2.4.11-3ubuntu3                     amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+
ii  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64                   2.4.11-3ubuntu3                     amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+
ii  libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev:amd64                 2.4.11-3ubuntu3                     amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+ - development files
ii  libwebkitgtk-dev:amd64                     2.4.11-3ubuntu3                     amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+ - development files
```

If you can help me figure out which packages I need for wxWebView to compile and what do I need to update in the Makefile to get it to compile.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: That all looks okay. The code and the error output is copy-pasted as-is, without any modifications?

Comment: @AnkurShah, are you able to compile the webview sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your version of wxWidgets was built without wxWebView support. You can check it by greeping for `wxUSE_WEBVIEW` in the `setup.h` file included in your wxWidgets package.

If this is indeed the case, you will need to build your own version of the library. Luckily, this is as simple as the usual `./configure && make` under Unix (you don't even need to install it, although you may do it, of course).

Last but not least: don't forget that you need to explicitly ask for webview library when using this class, i.e. use `wx-config --libs std,webview` instead of just `wx-config --libs`.